# How to sum selected numbers in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

For the following XML,

```
<numbers>
  <number>33</number>
  <number>34.4</number>
  <number>33.8</number>
  <number>33.43</number>
  <number>34.46</number>
  <number>35</number>
  <number>33.49</number>
  <number>33.00</number>
</numbers>
```

how can I write an XPath expression that will return the sum of all numbers which round off to 34?

Desired selection (text output): 102.66

Comment: If the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34216170/290085) solves your problem, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) it.  If not, please follow-up and say how we might help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Both of the following XPath expressions will return `102.66` (the sum of the numbers that round to 34) as requested:*

### XPath 1.0 Solution <sup><sub><sub>(Works in XPath 2.0 too)</sub></sub></sup>

```
sum(//number[round(.) = 34])
```

### XPath 2.0 Solution <sup><sub><sub>(Just to show a for loop example)</sub></sub></sup>

```
sum(for $n in //number return if (round($n) = 34) then $n else 0)
```